# Como extraer un dato de una cadena JSON en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Necesito extraer un dato de un campo SQL concatenado.

```
{ "coreBankingSimulatorId": "999" , "coreOmaId": "111", "cuit": "20041775034", "documentType": "DNI", "documentNumber": "20041775034" }
```

El dato que tengo que extraer es `20041775034` únicamente `"cuit"`.

El motor es [Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/).

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Hola Gaston, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprendas como funciona la plataforma. Por favor, utiliza la opción [edit] y agrega: ¿que motor de BBDD utilizas? ¿que has intentado? agrega la definición de la tabla. En tu ejemplo `cuit` y `documentNumber` son iguales, ¿cual necesitas? Saludos!

Comment: Es una cadena en formato JSON y el estándar SQL como tal no tiene soporte para JSON. Hay motores que tienen distintos grados de soporte, pero si no indicas el motor, la pregunta no se puede responder.

Comment: Es importante que indiques que motor de bd usas como dijo jachguate. Aun si no tienen soporte para JSON, se puede extraer el dato pero el código será distinto para cada motor.

Comment: Ya realice la edición

Comment: ¿El JSON lo obtienes de un archivo o lo tienes en una variable?

Comment: Segun la doc de microsoft se obtiene con: SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    cuits VARCHAR(100) '$.cuit', );
Donde @json es el nombre de la variable, pero no se, nunca he usado SQL del microsoft pero aqui esta la doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#convert-json-collections-to-a-rowset

Answer (score 0):

En SQLServer dispones de la función `JSON_VALUE` (a partir de la versión 2014 de SQL Server).

Documentación: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Puedes ejecutar una SELECT de este estilo para obtener un valor que está dentro de una campo que contiene un JSON:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS,
 JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.info.address.town') AS DIRECCION
FROM PERSONAS
```

Answer (score 0):

Si en una tabla tienes el campo 'CAMPO_JSON' donde se encuentran registrados los JSON, entonces puedes obtener un valor en específico de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
       JSON_VALUE(T.CAMPO_JSON,'$.cuit') AS 'CUIT'
FROM TABLA T
```

Así obtienes el valor de ese key en el JSON en una columna de tabla, y puedes hacer lo mismo para los demás campos.

Espero haberte ayudado.